# How to set htaccess to get parameters from user friendly URL to use with JS

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I would like users to see this pretty URL:

```
www.example.com/michael
```

and my code to be able to get it as variable through GET:

```
www.example.com?user=michael
```

On the **JavaScript** side I am testing it with this:

```
var userId = getQueryString('user');
console.log("user="+userId);
```

On the **.htaccess** side I'm using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?user=$1 [L]
```

When I load "www.example.com/michael" I do not get the redirect to 404, which is good. But the console outputs "user=null". It doesn't get the parameter through the GET. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess`, write the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9])/?$ /index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

So you can access your site typing `www.example.com/michael` or `www.example.com/michael/` or even `www.example.com/MICHAEL`

If you want to get the `user` parameter in JavaScript, use the code below:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const username = urlParams.get('user');
```

But remember that JavaScript will not detect parameter `user` if you're using `Rewrite` mode, because in the point of view of the browser, the URL is "/michael" and not "/?user=michael". JavaScript only looks to the friendly path.

You can use redirect instead, so when someone access typing "/michael", you redirect the user to "/?user=michael".

EDIT: Another solution is to parse the entire URL, catching the first "/" block of the URL `www.example.com/michael`. For example:

```
var username = location.href.substring(location.protocol.length).substr(2).substring(location.href.substring(location.protocol.length).substr(2).indexOf('/') + 1);
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Sorry, but no, it does not. I do not have index.php and I am not using PHP. I have an index.html in the root. Also, I shouldn't get that 404 error.

Comment: @HarunAlikadić it's only an example! Just replace index.php for index.html or whatever! Take a look at my EDIT comment.

Comment: @HarunAlikadić JavaScript will never see as `/index.html?user=michael` because Rewrite it's not for using with JS. JavaScript only looks to window.location.href and in this case it's `www.example.com/michael` and it will be what JavaScript can parse.

Comment: I understand that probably best solution would be to use redirect instead, so when someone access typing "/michael", I redirect the user to "/?user=michael". But at this moment, with your htaccess script, when I access "/michael" I get 404 error. Why?

Comment: @HarunAlikadić try `RewriteRule /^([A-Za-z0-9])/?$ /index.html?user=$1 [NC,L]` Look at the `/^`